# SQL - Getting all of the results from two tables

Tags: sql

Sorry, i'm new to this so this might be a very basic question!!

I have two tables with some overlapping data.

Table one has **customer_name**, **customer_address**, **country**, **gender**, and many other columns.

Table two also has **customer_name** and **customer_address**, but has different data to table one. Table two also has other columns which I wish to ignore.

I want to extract all of the **customer_name**'s and **customer_address**' from both table 1 and 2, along with **country** and **gender** from table 1, and put them in another table.

If anyone has any suggestions i'd really appreciate hearing them!

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Based on your requirement, looks like you need Union but cannot be sure unless we see some sample data and expected output. Refer [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056). Dont forget to mention Database/Version you are using

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `UNION`:

```
SELECT customer_name, customer_address, country, gender
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT customer_name, customer_address, '', ''
FROM table2
```

Note that `UNION` removes duplicate rows to create one *distinct* result set.

If you want all rows from both tables, even duplicates if they exist, use `UNION ALL` instead.

**Edit: To only show `table2` customers/addresses that aren't in `table1`**

There are a lot of approaches to this, but I like `NOT EXISTS()`:

```
SELECT customer_name, customer_address, country, gender
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT customer_name, customer_address, '', ''
FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM table1 t1
                  WHERE t1.customer_name = t2.customer_name
                  AND t1.customer_address = t2.customer_address)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked!!

However, as table2 has all of the names and addresses from table 1 - plus a few more -  I'm getting quite a lot of repeating data. Is there any way to just get the customer_names and customer_addresses in table2 that aren't in table1? 

Thanks!

Comment: SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM Table2 EXCEPT SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM Table1;

Comment: @Sam Glad it worked, I updated my answer to remove the repeated name/addresses

Comment: Regarding UNION it's worth noting that when no duplicates can occur it's better to use UNION ALL because it doesn't require sorting to remove dups.

Comment: It works!!! I used your edit Aaron, so thank you so so much!  Thanks Talmage, as well!